# Subspace clustering with random transformation

Tags: classification, cluster-analysis, linear-algebra, projection, pca

One approach for clustering a high dimensional dataset is to use linear transformation, and the most common approaches are PCA and random projection (where random projection arises from the Johnson-Lindenstrauss Lemma). I was wondering why we can't use other random transformation  s like when our transformation matrix R was drawn from a uniform distribution?

Answer (score 1):

There are many random projections in use, such as Achlioptas.

- Achlioptas, D. (2001, May).
   Database-friendly random projections.
   In Proceedings of the twentieth ACM SIGMOD-SIGACT-SIGART symposium on Principles of database systems (pp. 274-281). ACM.

J-L only proves there is at least one with the desired properties, but it does not give an actual projection. iirc, uniform random was not shown to satisfy these optimality criterions.